# Android: while i select an item from navigation drawer, it is not moving to the new screen

Tags: android, navigation, fragment

[when i set the size of viewerpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGWMO.png) **[i want output like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Lqu.png)**

I set `Tabs` in Home as a footer menu.
 the code is as follow:

**Home.Java**

```
package com.example.sachin.omcommunication;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    Fragment newFragment;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher

    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, new HomePage());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new HomePage(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        adapter.addFragment(new FourFragment(), "Four");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }
        public void addFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_Logout) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
            }
            else if (id == R.id.action_Exit) {
            finish();
            return true;

            }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            // Handle the action
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, new HomePage());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.myvisit) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, new Visit());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.myorder) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, new Order());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.mypaymnet) {
            Fragment newFragment = new Payment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.commit();


        } else if (id == R.id.mydelivery) {
            Fragment newFragment = new Delivery();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.DailyTask) {
            Fragment newFragment = new AddTask();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.Scheduletask) {
            Fragment newFragment = new ScheduleTask();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.onetimetask) {
            Fragment newFragment = new OneTimeTask();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.myattendence) {
            Fragment newFragment = new Attendence();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.lapp) {
            Fragment newFragment = new LeaveApplication();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.profile) {
            Fragment newFragment = new Profile();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.action_Logout) {
            Fragment newFragment = new HomePage();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.commit();
            return true;

            }



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, i want to move to the `HomePage` screen  while i select home in navigation drawer.

**HomePage.Java**

```
    package com.example.sachin.omcommunication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HomePage extends Fragment {

    public HomePage(){}
    View view;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_visit, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("HomePage");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home_page, container, false);

    }
   }
```

Here, posted the layout

**content_home.xml**

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
<!--

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
-->

        <include android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            ></include>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/framelayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >


</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

as same as `HomePage.Java` i set other `.java` files

Answer (score 0):

```
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.drawer_how:

                          FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, new HomePage());
                         fragmentTransaction.commit();
                         return true;

   // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                 .....

                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Somethings Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                }
            }
        });
```